# The Form validation is not working

Tags: php

I want to display the error if user entered a duplicate name. But, it's not working. It keeps the name inserted even it's same. So, here is my code :

```
$namaErr = "";
$error==false;
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
if(isset ($_POST['nama'])){
$nama = $_POST['nama'];
$query ='SELECT nama FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE nama="' . $nama . '" LIMIT 
1';
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$totalNumRowResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($totalNumRowResult > 0){
$error=true;
$namaErr="Nama ini telah digunakan!!";
} 
}
```

If no error, it will inserted in database :

```
else{
$query="INSERT INTO daftar_pengguna(nama) VALUES 
('$nama')";
$res = mysqli_query($query);
header('Location:index.php?registered=true');  
}    
}
```

I've searched all question like mine but, no luck.

Comment: You have double } bracket for last if, which is not happening correctly for the Else { block... Also I see few issues with your code for security. I suggest you do some sanitization for the post variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two things:

1. Merge the if conditions to one block , this will remove the braces confusion had as I noted in above comment and also noted by Sujith.
2. Also I suggest you sanitize the $_POST variable before sending to Database query...

See code below with the suggested modifications:

```
<?php

$namaErr = "";
$error = false;

# Merge condition checks in One block using && (AND)
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) && isset($_POST['nama'])) {

$nama = $_POST['nama'];

# Sanitize the input before running into Database query
$nama = filter_var($nama, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$query ='SELECT nama FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE nama="' . $nama . '" LIMIT 
1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$totalNumRowResult = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($totalNumRowResult > 0){
  $error=true;
  $namaErr="Nama ini telah digunakan!!";
} 
else{
  $query="INSERT INTO daftar_pengguna(nama) VALUES ('$nama')";
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  header('Location:index.php?registered=true');  
}
}
```

Comment: where that I should put the another curly bracket?you're missing one curly bracket

Comment: It's not working sir. It insert the duplicate name :( I'm so tired of this....feels like I want to give up

Comment: hey.. it's working.. I exit the google chrome, reopen it and try it again..it works!! thank u so much Mohsin. :)

Comment: One more question sir, can I make the text field display the error before user press the Enter button ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! For your second question, I think you will need Ajax for that, which can query database and show result/error without pageload.. it will add just lot of complexity into your code at this level so I suggest to keep it simple and let the Enter button load the page and show error, add link back to original page so they can try again...

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with ther braces. This should work

```
$namaErr = "";
$error==false;
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
   if(isset ($_POST['nama'])){
      $nama = $_POST['nama'];
           $query ='SELECT nama FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE nama="' .$nama . '" LIMIT 1';
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $totalNumRowResult = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($totalNumRowResult > 0){
 $error=true;
 $namaErr="Nama ini telah digunakan!!";
  } 
 else{
    $query="INSERT INTO daftar_pengguna(nama) VALUES 
    ('$nama')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    header('Location:index.php?registered=true');  
    }    
    }
  }
```

Comment: it's also not working sir. It inserted the name that is same like name inserted in the database before. :(

Answer (score 0):

try with this query :

```
$query ='SELECT nama FROM daftar_pengguna WHERE nama="' . $nama . '" ';
```